# Is it necessary to give direction:rtl to the input text field?

Tags: arrays, html, right-to-left

I am developing a colorpicker widget in which we support **RTL**. We have a hex field with # as prefix which is an input text field. If I give direction:rtl to the text field, it acts different, the typed character appends to the text but the cursor is to the left of the text.

To verify this, I changed the Language to Arabic and worked in Mac. When I choose the English keyboard, the input field is ltr, only the text alignment is to the right and When I choose the Arabic keyboard, the input field becomes rtl. If the os itself handles the text field based on keyboard language, is it necessary to give **direction:rtl** to the hex field in colorpicker?

**Note:**
   If I give rtl to the hex field, **#** gets attached to the end if the first letter is an alphabet, it gets prefixed to the text, if the first letter is a numeric.
You can check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/brindhaa10/cv04o8wr/

Code:

```
  <div class="rtl">
  <h4>
      RTL 
  </h4>
   <div class="row">  
       <input value="#ffffff" /> 
       <span> In RTL, when <b>#</b> precedes an alphabet, it is repositioned to the end </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <input value="#000fff" /> 
       <span> In RTL, when <b>#</b> precedes a number, it is not repositioned. </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Same problem arises for **percentage field**, **currency field** etc... If it is RTL, is it correct to reposition the symbols Ex: **100%** will be shown as **%100** in RTL.

Comment: Seems like you'd want to check with a native Arabic speaker who is a developers as they'd be the ones to know what gets flipped and what doesn't. It's not trivial, as I know I've corrected a mistake before.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend the directional setting through to neutral and weak characters with the `RLM` characters which can be encoded as `&rlm;` or `&#x200F;`. So, basically, all you need to do is append the `RLM` character at the end of the `#` character...

```
<input value="#&#x200F;000fff" />
```

See snippet below...

```html
<div style="direction:rtl">
  <input value="#&rlm;00ffff" />
</div>
```

Comment: This works only if we internally set the value from js, not when the user inputs. Moreover should the # be suffixed? @Leo

Comment: @Rohini yup, you will have to listen for `keyup` and `paste` events on the input to append the `RLM` character